# Should I enable filter after disabling it in Doctrine or it will be automatically enabled in the next request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony project and I'm using global filters, which I need to disable in just one controller action. Should I enable them after finishing my work with the not filtered results or they will be automatically enabled on the next request? Also should I use `clear()` method of EntityManager after enabling back the filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if your Doctrine filter is enabled by default, you don't need to enable your filter after disabled it.

According to the Doctrine [Filter documentation](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/filters), if you have a configuration as below:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        filters:
            myFilter:
                class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Filters\MyFilter
                enabled: true
                ...
```

And you disabling the filter inside your controller by using:

```
public function homepageAction(Request $request)
{
    ....
    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $filters = $em->getFilters()
                  ->disable('myFilter');
    ....
}
```

The filter is disabled for the full Request. But if you request another Controller were you do not disable the filter, the filter will be applied.